# How to read files sequentially in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have .txt files name like below

```
2019_05_01_11_26_39_abc
2019_05_02_12_06_40_abc
2019_05_03_15_20_39_abc
........................
2020_06_01_10_26_38_abc
2020_06_02_11_26_39_abc
.....................
2020_07_01_14_16_39_abc
```

I am using code below to read the files

```
import glob
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
x=[]
for f in glob.glob('*abc.txt'):
   print(f)
   df1=pd.read_csv(f,delimiter='\t', skiprows=range(0, 25))
   x.append(df1)
all_data = pd.concat(x,axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False,sort=False)
ray=pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(all_data.shape)
ray.to_csv('name.csv',index=False)
```

Files are not reading sequentially and is not writing sequentially in name.csv file.
How to resolve that?

Comment: `glob.glob` is not ordered same as `-ls u`, so you'll need to give us more information on what you mean by sequential, in any event read [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
sorted(glob.glob("*abc.txt"))
```

This should sort them in order by name.